# Replicating ActiveMQ shared database

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, database-replication, master-slave

We have configured ActiveMQ to use [JDBC Master Slave](https://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-master-slave). Our data center is an active and passive model. So we are thinking of replicating database that is used for Master-Slave from Active center to Passive center. But we are seeing three tables `activemq_msgs`, `activemq_lock` and `activemq_ack`. We are not sure which one or all to replicate to passive center and even if replicates whether bring up Master-Slave using replicated database works. This is the first time we are configuring and we don't find many documents in the internet to get started. Please provide your inputs.

Comment: @JustinBertram Sorry, I have corrected the table names now. Name of the last table is activemq_ack. Like I mentioned in the question, ours is Active-Passive datacenter. So in case of failover to Passive, we want unprocessed messages from active to be available in the passive center.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the "active" broker creates and uses those tables in the database then it stands to reason that the "passive" broker would too once it becomes active. In fact, it stands to reason that any table created by the "active" broker would be used by the "passive" broker once it becomes active. Therefore you should replicate **all** ActiveMQ related database tables.